# Copying excel Data to new worksheet Error 1004

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy certain information from cells into another spread sheet. I have a For loop which loops through the rows. The program bugs out when I try to copy the cells into the new spread sheet.
Should I be using range ? And do I need to say the worksheet before cells ?

This is just a sample of the code :

```
Set myOtherSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
For Each WkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If WkSht.Name = "Sheet1" Then
j = 0
For r = 6 To 1000

myOtherSheet.Cells(j, 1).Value = WkSht.Cells(r, 2)
myOtherSheet.Cells(j, 2).Value = Match
```

There Error I get is a 1004 object defined error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might caused by `j = 0` .. there's no rows 0 .. at least it should be ..

```
j = 1
```

Comment: @Bawn .. no, that's typical error from all of us .. so, if this help .. feel free to make a green tick ... :)

Comment: Thanks again! Had to wait 5 minutes before I gave the tick  :)